# App breaks after switching from localhost DB to mLab mongodb URI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

I've expanded on a chat app project from a node course that utilizes express and socket.io. I've incorporate more routes that facilitate /signup /login /logout functionality. Everything works perfectly in the local environment. If I simply change my mongodb URI to my mLab sandbox link, the app's login route breaks. I have searched countless threads for a solution, but none of the suggestions have worked. I am reasonably new to node, so I may just be missing something that would be obvious to seasoned devs.

**Here's the error that is thrown:**

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at User.findOne (/Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/server.js:128:27)
    at /Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4533:16
    at process.nextTick (/Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2584:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at /Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4535:13
    at process.nextTick (/Users/B/Desktop/shadow-gab/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2584:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Here is the POST route that crashes the app:**

```
    app.post('/chat', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.screenname) {
    console.log(req.body);

    User.findOne({ screenname: req.body.screenname }, (err,doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send('error occured');
      } else if (!doc) {
        res.status(500).send('Account doesn\'t exist. Please sign up.');
      } else if (doc) {
        let valid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, doc.password);

        if (!valid) {
          res.status(500).send('Incorrect Password');
        } else if (valid) {
          req.session.screenname = req.body.screenname;
          console.log(req.session);
          io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('New user connected');

            socket.on('join', (params, callback) => {
              if (!isRealString(req.body.screenname) || !isRealString(req.body.room)) {
                return callback('Name and room name are required');
              }

              socket.join(req.body.room);
              users.removeUser(socket.id);
              users.addUser(socket.id, req.body.screenname, req.body.room);

              io.to(req.body.room).emit('updateUserList', users.fetchUserList(req.body.room));
              socket.emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin', `Welcome to ${req.body.room} room`));
              socket.broadcast.to(req.body.room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin', `${req.body.screenname} has joined`));
              callback();

            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/chat.html'));
});
```

It would seem that the most common response to similar questions have been to look for places where you try to make more than one response to the request, but I don't see anywhere where i do that.

Again, I can simply switch the db url to my local machine and everything works perfect. Any direction would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**: The app is broken on the first login attempt, but if I use the logout route and then log *back* in, the app works. Still not sure what is causing this

Comment: its happening because you have one res.sendFile() at the end, if any of failure cases your app will send multiple responses hence Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Comment: @Vishal-Lia so would my solution be to move my res.sendFile call? or is it a matter of tracking down where my error is happening? Am i handling the request wrong? I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve this issue

Comment: Yes you need to move it. You should code in a way where all errors should be handled, so you can figure out cause of errors as well as making sure app doesn't crash.